# Command Line Arguments - Set Timeout Limit when Running Python Code

Tags: python, bash, command, timeout, arguments

I have a bash file in which I execute a python code in a for loop several times. I want to set a timeout so that if the python code takes more than a certain time then we go to the next iteration.
How can I add timeout to my bash code line when compiling and running the python file? 
This is the current line I use for running the python code:

```
python hw.py
```

I want to have something like this:

```
python hw.py timeout=120
```

Comment: You want the logic in `bash` or in `python`?

Comment: I need it in bash, I am not able to edit the python file, I am giving different inputs to the python file each time in a for loop and want it to kill python with a timeout limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` command in `bash`:

```
timeout 120 python hw.py
```

That will kill the python process if it executes for more that 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want the argument to be parsed into the Python script.

Try [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--timeout', help='timeout of script',action = 'store')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Parse `args.timeout` to the script that you need.

```
from time import time 
start = time()
for loop: # the for loop you mentioned

    if (time() - start) > timeout:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot edit the python files.