# Using "timeout" batch command to run python with args

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, timeout

In order to run python from cmd file I need only to run:

```
python file_name.py
```

In order to add a timeout, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269744/1452221) we should only do something like that:

```
timeout time_in_secs python file_name.py
```

But how to run a python with args, something like that?

```
timeout time_in_secs python file_name.py --cli_arg="cli_arg"
```

Comment: The [`timeout` command](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) in Windows is nothing but an equivalent to `sleep`, hence it waits for a certain amount of time; to kill the Python process after a certain amount of time you will have to write a script (probably using [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to parallelly run the Python task, [`tasklist`](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) to identify the correct task and to get its identifier, [`timeout`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) to await the timeout and [`taskkill`](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) to eventually kill the task)…

Comment: The question and answer in your provided link, was specific to the `B`ourne `A`gain `SH`ell, not `cmd.exe`.